# How to copy file from docker image ecr to aws lambda

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, jmeter, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am using jmeter + ECS( docker runtime) . I deployed docker image to ECR by cdk deploy and run ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] with cli

```
jmeter -n -t JMeter.jmx -l test-report.xml
```

I am using lambda to trigger the taskDefinition, below are example code in lambda.

```
const handler = async (event, context) => {
const ecs = new ECS();

await ecs.runTask({
    // code run
}).promise();

return;}
module.exports = { handler };
```

I want to copy file test-report.xml to folder /tmp/ of lambda . Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda function invocation is actually going to exit, and cease to exist, before the ECS task finishes running. The Lambda function invocation will probably exit before the ECS task even enters the "RUNNING" state.

There will be no opportunity for the Lambda function to get access to the output files generated by the ECS task.

You need to rethink how you are handling those output files. I recommend having your ECS task copy the output file to an S3 bucket as the last thing it does before it exits. Then you could have another Lambda function that is triggered by the S3 bucket when new objects are uploaded, which could then read the file from S3 and do whatever you need to do with the file at that point.